# Finding Java classes, functions and members that don't have Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I used to use Doxygen, which produced a nice report listing items that were had not been documented. Is there any way I can generate a similar report of missing Javadoc comments in an Eclipse Java project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a "report" as such, but you can configure Eclipse to report missing (and malformed) JavaDoc comments as warnings or even errors.

You can do that either on a per-workspace basis (Window -> Preferences - > Java -> Compiler -> Javadoc) or on a per-project basis (select project -> Right-Click -> Properties -> Java Compiler - > Javadoc).

Comment: Using a new problems view and the configure contents dialog (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm) I have exactly what I need. Thanks Joachim.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a cross-IDE (or rather a no-IDE) solution, you might also use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html), which can be configured to check javadoc on various levels (package, classes, methods, etc.)

Comment: Checkstyle has actually become our preferred tool, in conjunction with Jenkins